# I can no longer build after building another project in android stadio

Tags: android, kotlin

I had created a project in agp 8.0.2 (let's call this project project A). When I then built https://github.com/KaterinaPetrova/kmm-ktor-sample, I got an error because I could not build this project. Then, after giving up building this `kmm-ktor-sample`, I tried to build project A, but I got a lot of errors and could not build it. Here is how the errors were displayed.

I have tried the following

- Quit android stadio and delete the .idea directory
- do a clean project and then build.

None of them worked.

```
> Task :androidApp:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':androidApp:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':androidApp:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :androidApp > project :shared
      > No matching variant of io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a component for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.0.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'commonMainMetadataElements' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosArm32ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosArm32MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'macosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'macosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'macosX64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosX64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'tvosX64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosArm32ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosArm32MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosX64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosX64MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosX86ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'watchosX86MetadataElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:2.3.1:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '8.0.2')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':androidApp:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some idea you can try to fix your problem :

1. Remove your .gradle and .idea folder
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Try to update your plugin
4. Disable and enable your plugins
5. Try to compile using command line
6. Remove Project A and B from Android Studio then opent project A
7. Uninstall android studio and reinstall it then try to open project A